# Calling a stored procedure in a trigger in SQL DEVELOPER

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to call the following stored procedure...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PRC_EXAMEN_SUELDO(fecha_hoy varchar2)
AS 
BEGIN
    IF fecha_hoy= 'WEDNESDAY' then
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20777, 'Los ' || fecha_hoy ||' no se puede cambiar el sueldo');
    END IF;
END;
```

...inside this trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_EXAMEN_SUELDO
BEFORE UPDATE OF SALARY ON EMPLOYEES
FOR EACH ROW   
DECLARE 
    HOY VARCHAR(50);
BEGIN 
    HOY:= TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'DAY');
    execute PRC_EXAMEN_SUELDO (HOY);
END;
```

But it throws the following error:

> LINE/COL  ERROR
>   --------- -------------------------------------------------------------
>   5/13      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "PRC_EXAMEN_SUELDO" when expecting one of the following:
>   := . ( @ % ; immediate
>   The symbol ":=" was substituted for "PRC_EXAMEN_SUELDO" to continue.
>   Errors: check compiler log

I'm using the HR schema of Oracle.

The purpose of the procedure is to check if the day sent is equal to the day of sysdate. If it is, it activates the error.

Supposedly, after compiling this line of code:

```
    set serveroutput on;
    update employees set salary = salary + 100 where employee_id = 100;
```

The trigger should check if according to the sysdate, the change can be done. Else, it throws the specified error.

The stored procedure works properly, but the trigger doesn't. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't need the EXECUTE

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot!

Comment: Cool. I added an answer in case you needed a quick look-see to the docs. Welcome to the wild, wonderful world of Oracle :)

Answer (score 0):

EXECUTE is a SQL*Plus command ([Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqpug/EXECUTE.html#GUID-A64F29C8-B5C7-426D-82E9-A8E85763F3D6)) for executing stored procedures, ad hoc

```
set serveroutput on
exec hello -- hello is a procedure that simply dbms_output 'hello' back
```

Running this in SQL Developer as a script, or in an interactive shell like SQL*Plus or SQLcl, I get

```
hello

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

But these clients have a command interpreter that deals with 'exec' which is short for EXECUTE. It's not part of the PL/SQL language though.

In your trigger body, you'd simply do:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_EXAMEN_SUELDO
    BEFORE UPDATE OF SALARY ON EMPLOYEES
    FOR EACH ROW   
    DECLARE 
    HOY VARCHAR(50);
    BEGIN 
    HOY:= TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'DAY');
    PRC_EXAMEN_SUELDO (HOY);
    END;
```